# Extract and combine data from huge Excel tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, metadata

I receive huge metadata excels (mastersheets with minimum 100.000 rows up until 1 million; columns vary from 10 to 30) containing data that I would need to extract based on a unique identifier (present in the first column of my master sheet).
For the moment I use LOOKUP to look for my unique identifier and extract the associated column I would need for my new sheet. However, As I extract more than 1 column (from 3 to 6), the calculation is extremely slow (30 minutes or more to calculate my sheet).

I use this formula

```
=IF(IF(LOOKUP(A2;STORED_NAME)=A2;"yes";"no")="yes";TRIM(LOOKUP(A2;STORED_NAME;FILENAME));"#####")
```

I have tried also with VLOOKUP but the calculation is also extremely slow. Filtering is also another nightmare and it takes forever.

Do you have any advice? Should I keep using Excel and use another formula? Or maybe should I look into something different (another program, another language, etc) that can also automatize the process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would look at writing some VBA code to do the heavy-lifting for you. The majority of the cost in what you're doing is waiting for the UI to refresh. If you use VBA and disable screen updates whilst you're filtering/extracting, it'll reduce the execution time dramatically.

Comment: Sounds like this is possible through PowerQuery available through Excel. You can connect almost any database, transform the data and view the results in Excel.

Comment: I have tried PowerQuery but it is also very slow when I have more than 500k rows, each operation takes extremely long and sometimes the data is truncated (it doesn't load all rows)

Comment: Consider migrating to a database

Comment: Power query is pretty powerful, it's should be able to manage your data. Please share what you've tried and we might suggest a better approach.

Comment: Are you copying these formulas through thousands of cells? If so, I would recommend VBA solutions to moving the data over formula solutions.

Comment: You can read this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance

Answer (score 0):

Using 30 columns, 29 of data, one with a `MOD()` formula in all million+ cells to give me an easy basis for different choices to test how fast a new output would populate, the following formula never felt like it took even a second to return a correct output set:

```
=FILTER(  INDEX(A:AD, ROW(1:1048576), {1,25}),  C:C=3)
```

`INDEX()` takes the data table and selects two columns from it, though of course, only the column with the desired data is needed from it as `FILTER()` filters based upon the condition irrespective of the first parameter (in which I used the `INDEX()`). In fact, for a single column, or a set of contiguous columns, `INDEX()` isn't even needed, just a simple range reference:

```
=FILTER( Y:Y, C:C=3)
```

I used the `INDEX()` function just to test larger sets of columns, and noncontiguous sets, to see how and if that delayed a response. I thought the noncontiguous choices would be the most time-consuming, but simply the most columns chosen for the return was actually the most time-consuming.

With all 30 utterly full columns (1,048,576 full cells per column), a change to the selection parameter took no more than 4 seconds to repopulate. And for all columns being included, cutting the `INDEX()` function out, just specifying A:AD, never took longer than 2, possibly 3 seconds.

You mention "filtering" in your post. I did NOT ever try non-formulaic filtering of any kind as I believe that was the kind of filtering you meant and assumed your reported frustration with filtering to be correct. The filtering here is completely formulaic.

I'm sure it's entirely possible that results would take a lot longer if many cells have formulas that Excel recalcs with a change to `FILTER()`'s condition parameter (volatile functions for example, though non-volatile functions (like my `MOD()` formula column) would not). But you said "data" which implies no formulas at all so... not thinking your data is materially different than my test data for Excel feeding it into an output.

It also seems possible that your frustrations occur downstream, that the creation of your output set is not the real issue, rather it is formulas that rely upon it perhaps causing it to have to recalc and recalc and recalc. With a 4 second response time, at most, even that doesn't seem like it could lead to 30 minute wait times, so I can't see a way to address that possibility too usefully.

The last big issue I can see with using `FILTER()` would be that you might have a very complicated set of conditions that perhaps even force Excel to create one output set after another inside the formula for the next layer in the conditions calculations. Since we just don't know those particulars, and obviously therefore don't know particulars, I can't address it. It doesn't seem like you'd leave something like that out of the post though, if your output selection conditions were complicated enough as surely that would be an obvious thing to include.